# Prevent Editing Specific Cell on Key Press devexpress gridview winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, keypress

My Question is about to disable and Enable focused cell of Grid View and change disable cell to color on Key press
but i don't have any idea how to do that I Have done specific row Enabled False using row state helper class But now i want to disable cell How can i do that?

[image: Grid Screen Shot Attached]

Comment: I assume you mean a `GridControl`?  What is supposed to trigger the change to enabled?  What keypress and is that somehow different than the trigger for enabled?

Comment: I am asking about the devexpress grid control

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridView's [ShowingEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.ShowingEditor.event) event:

```
private void gridViewTest_ShowingEditor(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) 
{
    GridView gridView = sender as GridView; 

    if(gridView.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "Product Name") // && <PUT OTHER CONDITIONS HERE>
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```